# How does this method determine the greatest common divisor?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math

> In mathematics, the greatest common divisor (gcd) of two or more integers, when at least one of them is not zero, is the largest positive integer that divides the numbers without a remainder. For example, the GCD of 8 and 12 is 4. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)

The following method is able to determine the GCD:

```
def gcd(a, b)
  if a % b == 0
    b
  else
    gcd(b, a % b)
  end
end
p gcd(4, 12)
#=> 4
```

How does this method work?

It makes sense if `a % b == 0` then `b` is the biggest number that can go into both `a` and `b`.

But why call the same method again but switch around the args and take the modulus again?

I'm not grokking the reasoning behind the `else` part.

**Edit:**

Adding some `puts` statements to make it clearer:

```
def gcd(a, b)
  puts "Inside gcd, a: #{a}, b: #{b}, a \% b: #{a % b}"

  if a % b == 0
    puts "Inside if, a: #{a}, b: #{b}, a \% b: #{a % b}"
    b
  else
    puts "Inside else, a: #{a}, b: #{b}, a \% b: #{a % b}"
    gcd(b, a % b)
  end
end

p gcd(55, 105)
```

stdout:

```
Inside gcd, a: 55, b: 105, a % b: 55
Inside else, a: 55, b: 105, a % b: 55
Inside gcd, a: 105, b: 55, a % b: 50
Inside else, a: 105, b: 55, a % b: 50
Inside gcd, a: 55, b: 50, a % b: 5
Inside else, a: 55, b: 50, a % b: 5
Inside gcd, a: 50, b: 5, a % b: 0
Inside if, a: 50, b: 5, a % b: 0
5
```

Comment: Maybe just add some `puts` statements to see what it does? Fun fact, Ruby has builtin `12.gcd(4)` function.

Comment: I think the method would be clearer if you just tried it out, say, on 55 and 105.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what is called an [Euclidean Algorithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanAlgorithm.html).

In order to understand why you need to swap the numbers and make another recursion call you need to understand what is the actual maths behind it. Check this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/JUzYl1TYMcU) out to see how Euclidean algorithm works. Otherwise, I wrote my explanation of the algorithm below.

---

## **Formal explanation of the Euclidean algorithm**:

> ***Input***
>
> - Two positive integers, a and b.
>
> ***Output***
>
> - The greatest common divisor, gcd, of a and b.
>
> ***Internal computation***
>
> - If a < b, exchange a and b.
> - Divide a by b and get the remainder, r. If r = 0, report b as the GCD of a and b.
> - Replace a by b and replace b by r. Return to the previous step.

---

**For example:**

```
gcd(40,7)

40 = 7(5) + 5 
 7 = 5(1) + 2
 5 = 2(2) + 1 <-- your gcd
 2 = 1(2) + 0
```

but, this implies that...

```
gcd(40,7) = gcd(7, gcd(40,7)) =
gcd(7, 5) = gcd(5, gcd(7, 5)) =
gcd(5, 2) = gcd(2, gcd(5, 2)) = 
gcd(2, 1) = 0
```

**when** `gcd(a,b) = 0`, b is **equal to** 1, so we **return** b

Now here is the **important part!** If we didn't swap numbers around we wouldn't be able to perform the necessary maths and, ultimately, track the location of b, which is our gcd.

---

So, the swap is essentially needed to keep the factors on the right. Try doing the maths without the swaps and you'll quickly see why it is important ;)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

The key fact is that, for each divisor g of b, we have g divides a if and only if g divides a % b (in particular, this holds for the GCD). This is by the identity a = (a / b) * b + a % b, where / is integer division, since g divides a (respectively, a % b), and g divides all multiples of b, including (a / b) * b, hence g divides a % b (respectively, a). The recursive call thus gives the correct result if it terminates, and it terminates because we always reduce the size of the input (except at the root call).

The reason to switch around the arguments is so that the larger number is the first argument, since 0 <= a % b < b for positive a and b. This ensures that the recursive calls make progress.