# Why does this function to obtain maximum common divisor does not compare which numer is greater

Tags: javascript, math

I am looking at examples of common divisor functions.

I see this one using Euclid's algorithm

```
var gcd = function(a, b) {  
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
return gcd(b, a % b);
};

console.log(gcd(126,553443));
```

But why does it not compare which number is the greatest between `a` and `b` before doing the first recursive call?

I mean, why is not

```
if (a > b)
  return gcd(a, b % a); 
else
  return gcd(b, a % b);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372341/how-does-this-method-determine-the-greatest-common-divisor) is another example. I don't see where the swapping is taking place

Comment: add `console.log(a,b)` before the `return gcd` to see what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` is less than `b`, then `a % b` will be `a`. Thus on the next iteration, `a` will be smaller than `b`.

Try it. 12 % 20 is 12 because the *quotient* is 0, and the *remainder* is 12.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it was dumb question